# Action Script 3.0 replace all occurrences in multiline String

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have some text:

```
1. Lorem &laquo;ipsum&raquo; dolor sit amet, consectetur<br/>
2. adipisicing &laquo;elit&raquo;, sed do eiusmod tempor<br/>
3. incididunt ut &laquo;labore&raquo; et dolore magna aliqua.<br/>
```

And I want to replace all "`&amp;laquo;`" to "`&amp;#171;`" and all "`&amp;raquo;`" to "`&amp;#187;`".

This replace only in first row:

```
txt.replace(new RegExp("&amp;laquo;","gi"),"&amp;#171;").replace(new RegExp("&amp;raquo;", "gi"),"&amp;#187;");
```

other rows still not changed.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: where this string is placed? multilined `TextField`?

Comment: Sorry guys,I was wrong. This expression works txt.replace(new RegExp("&amp;laquo;","gi"),"&amp;#171;").replace(new RegExp("&amp;raquo;", "gi"),"&amp;#187;");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your regex 'multiline':

```
new RegExp("&amp;laquo;","gim")
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
txt.split( "&amp;laquo;" ).join( "&amp;#171;" ).split( "&amp;raquo;" ).join( "&amp;#187;" );
```

split breaks your string into an array of pieces connected by the text in the parameter.
join glues the pieces back into a string and inserts the parameter between each piece :D

Note that each method creates an array (the pieces) or a string (the glued together pieces) so you should do txt = txt.split(...